# Mule ESB: JMS selector expression not working

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a Mule integration that implements the pub-sub model. The publisher publishes the message to a topic and the subscriber is configured to receive the messages from this topic. I want to have this subscriber receive the messages only if a custom property named 'ENTITY_TYPE' has values either of the following: 'accounts', 'contacts' or 'cases'. Unfortunately this is not working (I mean the subscriber doesn't receive the message at all). Here is the code snippets:

**Publisher:**

AccountsFlow:

```
<set-property propertyName="ENTITY_TYPE" value="accounts" doc:name="Set Entity Type"/>
<jms:outbound-endpoint  connector-ref="Active_MQ_Publisher" doc:name="Publish Accounts" topic="${activemq.sfdc.topicname}" tracking:enable-default-events="true"/>
```

ContactsFlow:

```
<set-property propertyName="ENTITY_TYPE" value="contacts" doc:name="Set Entity Type"/>
<jms:outbound-endpoint  connector-ref="Active_MQ_Publisher" doc:name="Publish Contacts" topic="${activemq.sfdc.topicname}" tracking:enable-default-events="true"/>
```

CasesFlow:

```
<set-property propertyName="ENTITY_TYPE" value="cases" doc:name="Set Entity Type"/>
<jms:outbound-endpoint  connector-ref="Active_MQ_Publisher" doc:name="Publish Cases" topic="${activemq.sfdc.topicname}" tracking:enable-default-events="true"/>
```

**Subscriber:**

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint  connector-ref="Active_MQ_Subscriber" doc:name="JMS" tracking:enable-default-events="true" topic="${activemq.sfdc.topicname}">
        <jms:selector expression="ENTITY_TYPE='accounts' OR ENTITY_TYPE='contacts' OR ENTITY_TYPE='cases'" />
</jms:inbound-endpoint>
<logger message="$$$: Entity Type = #[message.inboundProperties['ENTITY_TYPE']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

If I remove the 'jms:selector' element, then I do see the output in the logs:

```
2015-06-18 15:58:19,574 INFO o.m.a.p.LoggerMessageProcessor [[sfdcjob].AccountsContactsCasesSubscriberFlow.stage1.02] $$$: Entity Type = sfdc.locationheader
```

Here is the env details:

Mule Standalone: 3.6.2 (Enterprise Edition)
OS: Cent OS 7
Message Broker: Active MQ 5.11.1
JVM for both Mule & Active MQ: 1.7.0.75

I certainly need to set the filter and interested to receive only the messages whose message property is set to one of the values defined previously (accounts, contacts, cases). Any idea why the JMS selector not working?

**Edit**: I tried another way to set the entity type in the publisher as follows and that also didn't work.

```
<jms:outbound-endpoint  connector-ref="Active_MQ_Publisher" doc:name="Publish Accounts" topic="${activemq.sfdc.topicname}" tracking:enable-default-events="true">
        <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties" scope="outbound">
            <add-message-property key="ENTITY_TYPE" value="accounts" />
        </message-properties-transformer>
</jms:outbound-endpoint>
```

Comment: Looking at the log line I see `Entity Type = sfdc.locationheader`, which is not in the list of accepted values in the selector. So it seems the selector is working fine but the setting of the entity type fails for any reason.

Comment: Also FTR this `ENTITY_TYPE='accounts' OR ENTITY_TYPE='contacts' OR ENTITY_TYPE='cases'` can be simplified to `ENTITY_TYPE IN ('accounts', 'contacts', 'cases')`

Comment: @DavidDossot - In my project, I do have it as 'sfdc.locationheader', but while I was posting this message, I renamed it to 'accounts' and so to simplify it, but forgot to update the logger line. The short story of this is that in the project, it is named correctly.

Comment: Thanks, in that case I'm at loss why it doesn't work :(

Comment: I don't understand this, but it started working again as designed without any changes when I restarted my workstation (it was not rebooted for several weeks).

Comment: Thanks for the update. You might have been running an old version of the Mule app or something similar. Please close the question because it's not really a reproducible problem.